# Got an error in laravel as:ErrorException Undefined variable: products

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am a newbie to Laravel and this is my first project. I am developing an e-commerce website. Up to now, I have finished the project with the help of StackOverflow and laracasts. Why I am getting this error?

I got an error as,
ErrorException Undefined variable: products

This is my controller.

```
CartController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;


class CartController extends Controller
{
    
    public function index()
{
     $products = Product::get();
     return view ('cart')->with(compact('products'));
     
 }

   
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function show($id)
    {
        $products = Product::find($id);
       
        return view('cart')->with(compact('product'));
   }
   
   
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

   
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my blade file.

cart.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.single')
@section('content')

 @foreach($products as $p) 
                            <tr class="">
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-32 font-size-26">×</a>
                                </td>
                              
                                <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">
                                    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid max-width-100 p-1 border border-color-1"  alt="Image Description"></a>
                                </td>
                                
                                <td data-title="Product">
                                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</a>
                                </td>
                               
                                <td data-title="Price">
                                    <span class="">LKR {{ $p ['prod_price'] }}.00</span>
                                </td>
                               
                                <td data-title="Quantity">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Quantity</span>
                                    <!-- Quantity -->
                                    <div class="border rounded-pill py-1 width-122 w-xl-80 px-3 border-color-1">
                                        <div class="js-quantity row align-items-center">
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <input class="js-result form-control h-auto border-0 rounded p-0 shadow-none" type="text" value="1">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-auto pr-1">
                                                <a class="js-minus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                    <small class="fas fa-minus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                </a>
                                                <a class="js-plus btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-outline-secondary rounded-circle border-0" href="javascript:;">
                                                    <small class="fas fa-plus btn-icon__inner"></small>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- End Quantity -->
                                </td>

                                <td data-title="Total">
                                    <span class="">$1,100.00</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
@endsection
```

This is my route.

web.php

```
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@index')->name('cart');
Route::get('/cart/{id}', 'CartController@show')->name('cart');
```

products table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('prod_name');
            $table->string('prod_brand')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cat_id');
            $table->string('prod_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_item_code')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_modal')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_size')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_weight')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_height')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_manufacturer')->nullable();
            $table->float('prod_price')->nullable();
            $table->float('prod_discount')->nullable();
            $table->float('prod_quantity')->nullable();
            $table->string('prod_image_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('cat_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Product Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Storage;

class Product extends Model
{
 
    
}
```

Comment: `index()` method of your controller has `$products` assigned to array but never defined, I guess you need to fetch your products from model and then assign records to `$products`

Comment: It means, do I need to add a foreach function?

Comment: It means you need something like `$products = Product::limit(10)->get();` before you assign it to array

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the index method of the controller. On the first line, you are trying to assign `$products`, but that variable does not exist.

```
public function index()
{
    $arr['products'] = $products;
    return view('cart')->with($arr);

}
```

You need to get all of your products to do this. Something like:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $arr['products'] = Product::all();
    return view('cart')->with($arr);

}
```

This example will just give you all of the products in your database. This is not really a good solution, as you can have a lot of products, making the response huge and expensive. To get around this, you can add pagination. Here is a simple example of implementing that:

You need to get all of your products to do this. Something like:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $limit = $request->input('limit', 10);
    $page = $request->input('page', 1);

    $arr['products'] = Product::paginate($limit, [], 'page', $page)->items();
    return view('cart')->with($arr);
}
```

Again, this is just an example to make you aware of this concept and is probably more for API responses and not view responses, like you are doing here, but nonetheless, something you need to know about eventually. Read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

**EDIT:** Since you are trying to show multiple products in the view, you will also have to iterate the products, so you can render them one by one. For this you need to read up on: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#loops

Comment: Actually my requirement is, I need to add a product to cart. For that do I need pagination?

Comment: No, you will only need pagination if you want to show a list of multiple products or another model. I just mentioned it due to the issue being in your index method, where you likely eventually will need pagination. Just mentioning it, as you will surely run into this requirement soon.

Comment: okay, thank you. I edited the index function please have a look. After I change like this got an error as- Property [prod_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bizzcomputer\resources\views\cart.blade.php)

Comment: Can you also add the Product model class to the original question? It is likely because `prod_name` does not exist on the Product, but you are trying to call it from the view: `<a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $products->['prod_name'] }}</a>`

Comment: I have also updated my answer. Please read the edit. This is related to your view and rendering of multiple items.

Comment: Thank you. I added foreach as I edited above, Then it shows all the products. But I need to show that particular product.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219604/discussion-between-zeenath-and-severindk).